# How to Move file in the same storage by just changing the path? (Android)

Tags: java, android, file-move

My Question is how to move file not copy by just changing the path of file system level
in android file.nenameTo(newpath); this method works only when I have path like this

```
File f = new File(/storage/Folder1/Folder2/image.png);
File newfile = new File((/storage/Folder1/Folder3/image.png);

f.renameTo(newfile);  // this method returns true
```

it works but when more then one parent folder change then it's not working

```
File f = new File(/storage/Folder1/Folder2/image.png);
File newfile = new File((/storage/Folder3/Folder4/image.png);

f.renameTo(newfile); // this method returns false

the following case also not work 

 File f = new File(/storage/Folder1/Folder2/image.png);
File newfile = new File((/storage/Folder3/image.png);

f.renameTo(newfile); // this method returns false
```

I want to move file like above
sorry for my English

Comment: You have to create the `"/storage/Folder3/Folder4/"` path first.

Comment: yes i created second path but it's not work

Comment: Did you try to copy the file from one location to the other then delete the original file?

Comment: yes but it takes time that's why i want this i saw an which doing the same thing which i want to achive

Comment: It takes time... **NO**. Because that's what a `File Move` operation really does: `File Copy + File Delete`.

Comment: in move when only one parent folder change this rename method works and its takes no time File f = new File(/storage/Folder1/Folder2/image.png);
File newfile = new File((/storage/Folder1/Folder3/image.png);

f.renameTo(newfile);  // this method returns true                    comparing to copy i want to achieve similar thing

Comment: @Der Golem if you copy 1gb file in computer in same drive and move same file both process takes different times i just want to same work

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/67538/discussion-between-muhammad-waqas-khan-abbasi-and-der-golem).

Comment: It takes more time on a file move. Because it does 2 different operations: copy + delete. File copy doesn't do the deletion, therefore it's faster.

Comment: no i want to tell you is file move is fast and file copy is slow

Answer (score 1):

You can only rename a file in Android if the src and dst are on the same mount point.  You don't specify either way.  Please consider using Files.move instead to avoid this potential issue and others.

Comment: Please read my Question it's mention that i have same mount point like  Path 1 :/storage/Folder1/Folder2/image.png Path2 :/storage/Folder3/Folder4/image.png

Comment: I read the question again.  You simply do not state that the mount point is the same.  "In the same storage" doesn't address this issue.  /storage/Folder1 could be on one partition while /storage/Folder3 is on another.  If the mount point is the same and the folder is there I would look hard at permissions.